# componentWillReceiveProps method unsafe

Tags: reactjs

I did find some logical explanation on `componentWillMount` getting deprecated in React17, but why is `componentWillReceiveProps` method getting deprecated for react components?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [react blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

> Like componentWillUpdate, componentWillReceiveProps might get called multiple times for a single update. For this reason it is important to avoid putting side effects in this method.

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to use **getDerivedStateFromProps** or **componentDidUpdate**, these provide everything you used to do in **componentWillReceiveProps**